# Table to table replication

Tags: mysql, replication

If I have two tables:

Table A - INNODB table

Table B - MEMORY table

Is it possible to have Table B mirror Table A using just MySQL? If so, how?

I'm not sure what else could be meant. I simply wish for all rows to appear in Table B, much like how replication works with whole databases.

Table B = Table A

Comment: didnt get your question ??..

Comment: sounds like you need to replicate mysql table ??

Comment: @imperium2335 is yours really a use case for the MEMORY storage engine? I think you would have to use triggers for all data changing operations on table A and populate Table B when the server starts with the use of the --init-file option, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

Comment: @VMai I am looking for a way to speed up read operations on some of my pages. The selects are very complex and using memcache isn't practical. So I thought of having MEMORY versions of tables for fast reads. But I did wonder about having a master-slave setup where all tables in the slave are memory, and read operations are done on the slave.